# Match Words and Add Quantities vb.net

Tags: vb.net, text

I am trying to program a way to read a text file and match all the values and their quantites. For example if the text file is like this:
Bread-10 Flour-2 Orange-2 Bread-3

I want to create a list with the total quantity of all the common words. I began my code, but I am having trouble understanding to to sum the values. I'm not asking for anyone to write the code for me but I am having trouble finding resources. I have the following code:

```
Dim query = From data In IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\User\Desktop\doc.txt")
                Let name As String = data.Split("-")(0)
                Let quantity As Integer = CInt(data.Split("-")(1))
                Let sum As Integer = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To query.Count - 1
        For j As Integer = i To 
                
        Next
```

Thanks

Comment: is each value set on a single line in the text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, lets break this down. And I not seen the LET command used for a long time (back in the GWBASIC days!).

But, that's ok.

So, first up, we going to assume your text file is like this:

```
Bread-10
Flour-2
Orange-2
Bread-3
```

As opposed to this:

```
Bread-10 Flour-2 Orange-2 Bread-3
```

Now, we could read one line, and then process the information. Or we can read all lines of text, and THEN process the data. If the file is not huge (say a few 100 lines), then performance is not much of a issue, so lets just read in the whole file in one shot (and your code also had this idea).

Your start code is good. So, lets keep it (well ok, very close).

A few things:
We don't need the LET for assignment. While older BASIC languages had this, and vb.net still supports this? We don't need it. (but you will see examples of that still floating around in vb.net - especially for what we call "class" module code, or "custom classes". But again lets just leave that for another day.

Now the next part? We could start building up a array, look for the existing value, and then add it. However, this would require a few extra arrays, and a few extra loops.

However, in .net land, we have a cool thing called a dictionary.

And that's just a fancy term of for a collection VERY much like an array, but it has some extra "fancy" features. The fancy feature is that it allows one to put into the handly list things by a "key" name, and then pull that "value" out by the key.

This saves us a good number of extra looping type of code.
And it also means we don't need a array for the results.
This key system is ALSO very fast (behind the scene it uses some cool concepts - hash coding).

So, our code to do this would look like this:

Note I could have saved a few lines here or there - but that would make this code hard to read.

Given that you look to have Fortran, or older BASIC language experience, then lets try to keep the code style somewhat similar. it is stunning that vb.net seems to consume even 40 year old GWBASIC type of syntax here.

Do note that arrays() in vb.net do have some fancy "find" options, but the dictionary structure is even nicer. It also means we can often traverse the results with out say needing a for i = 1 to end of array, and having to pull out values that way.

We can use for each.

So this would work:

```
    Dim MyData() As String      ' an array() of strings - one line per array
    MyData = File.ReadAllLines("c:\test5\doc.txt")  ' read each line to array()

    Dim colSums As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)   ' to hold our values and sum them
    Dim sKey As String
    Dim sValue As Integer

    For Each strLine As String In MyData
        sKey = Split(strLine, "-")(0)
        sValue = Split(strLine, "-")(1)
        If colSums.ContainsKey(sKey) Then
            colSums(sKey) = colSums(sKey) + sValue
        Else
            colSums.Add(sKey, sValue)
        End If
    Next

    ' display results
    Dim KeyPair As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)
    For Each KeyPair In colSums
        Debug.Print(KeyPair.Key & " = " & KeyPair.Value)
    Next
```

The above results in this output in the debug window:

```
Bread = 13
Flour = 2
Orange = 2
```

I was tempted here to write this code using just pure array() in vb.net, as that would give you a good idea of the "older" types of coding and syntax we could use here, and a approach that harks all the way back to those older PC basic systems.

While the dictionary feature is more advanced, it is worth the learning curve here, and it makes this problem a lot easier. I mean, if this was for a longer list? Then I would start to consider introduction of some kind of data base system.

However, without some data system, then the dictionary feature is a welcome approach due to that "key" value lookup ability, and not having to loop. It also a very high speed system, so the result is not much looping code, and better yet we write less code.

Comment: Thank you albert, I appreciate the help. I will learn the dictionary route as well. I am having a lot of issues fine recent support for this language. So I appreciate the time you took out of your day for this!

Comment: I think the `Let` in this context is "special" and used for setting up the Linq query, rather than the historical use signifying variable assignment.  I wouldn't assume the OP has any particular historical knowledge.

Comment: Ah, yes - that is possible! I gracility apologize to the poster if my narrative and assumption was incorrect.